# Make bootstrap link active in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar has links which are active according to the base URL of the current page.

PHP Function :

```
function Match($requestUri){

    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

    if ($current_file_name == $requestUri) 
        return "active";
    }
```

Link:

```
echo "<li class=".Match("cms").'nav-item'."><a href='/cms/index.php'>Home</a>"
```

What I am getting:

```
<li class="activenav-item"><a href="/cms/index.php">Home</a></li>
```

What Should be:

```
<li class="active nav-item"><a href="/cms/index.php">Home</a></li>
```

What should I do to add whitespace after **active**?

Comment: echo "<li class=".Match("cms").'  nav-item'."><a href='/cms/index.php'>Home</a>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just include the space inside the string literal:

```
echo "<li class='".Match("cms")." nav-item'><a href='/cms/index.php'>Home</a>"
                                 ^
```

Even if `Match` would return an empty string, this would be valid HTML - the leading space is then just ignored by the browser.

Note that you are also mixing up single and double quotes. If you construct a piece of HTML like this, it is best to use double quotes for PHP string delimiters, and single quotes for HTML attributes (as this allows for [variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)).

Answer (score 1):

As a fair alternative, you can also include the space in your return statement.

```
if ($current_file_name == $requestUri) 
    return "active ";
}
```

However, are you sure that you're actually getting the result you think you're getting? This line here is not quoted correctly.

```
echo "<li class=".Match("cms").'nav-item'."><a href='/cms/index.php'>Home</a>"
```

You should quote it as such:

```
echo "<li class='".Match("cms")."nav-item'><a href='/cms/index.php'>Home</a>";
```